# Finding the boundary conditions for specific heat PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, heat-equation, linear-pde

I have recently read a paper on heating a metal bar. The heat equation is used to analyze the system but as I can't find the right boundary conditions used to solve the heat equation. I'm hoping that by explaining the experiment here someone could point out what I'm missing.

A metal rod (of length $L$) is held at a constant temperature $T=T_0$ at the $x=L$. At the end $x=0$ heat is generated that results in a constant heat flux of $\vec{q}=\frac{\dot{Q}}{A}$.

Solving the equation for the initial conditions, they get that $T(x,0)=T_0+(L-x)\frac{\dot{Q}}{AK}$.

I've been able to follow the paper this far where I get:

\begin{array}{lkl}
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{D}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} & \textrm{Heat equation} \\
T(L,t)=T_0 & \textrm{Boundary condition} \\
T(x,0)=T_0+(L-x)\frac{\dot{Q}}{KA} & \textrm{Initial condition}
\end{array}

I only know how to solve PDEs with the variable separation method and I don't see how I could apply it here. I feel like I'd need another boundary condition.

I'm not looking for a solution as I'd like to get it myself but I don't even know where to start or where to get that extra boundary condition.

Thanks for the help and sorry for any spelling or grammar mistakes I might have made as english is not my first language

In case anyone is wondering the name of the paper is "Measurement of the thermal properties of a metal using a relaxation method" by John N. Fox and Richard H. Mc.Master

Comment: There is a boundary condition at the heated end given by $\left.\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0}= -\frac{\dot{Q}}{KA}$ (Fourier’s Law).

Comment: Are you sure that $T_0 + (L - x)\frac{\dot{Q}}{KA}$ is the intitial condition? Because that is also the steady-state temperature distribution. If that’s the initial condition too, then the distribution will not evolve in time.

Comment: @JasonZimba, you are right, the equation is the steady-state distribution not the initial condition. I thought you could use it as an initial condition

Comment: In the experiment being described, it’s possible that the initial temperature distribution is unknown or unspecified. No matter what the initial temperature distribution is, however, that distribution will decay away as transients, leaving behind the steady-state final distribution.